# ImportError when integrating unittesting into bash script

Tags: python, bash, unit-testing, command-line, environment-variables

Assume a folder '*lib/*' that contains several unittesting files (ending in '*__unittest.py*'). I would like to conduct unittesting on all test files in said folder by calling a bash script called `TESTING`.

```
michael$ python -m unittest discover -s ./lib/ -p '*__unittest.py'
...................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 19 tests in 0.001s

OK

michael$ bash <(python -m unittest discover -s ./lib/ -p '*__unittest.py')
...................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 19 tests in 0.002s

OK

michael$ echo "python -m unittest discover -s ./lib/ -p '*__unittest.py'" > TESTING

michael$ bash <(cat TESTING)
EEE
======================================================================
ERROR: CheckingOps__unittest (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: CheckingOps__unittest
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ImportError: No module named 'Bio'
```

It would appear that I cannot conduct unittesting by calling the bash script, as, then, Python does not import the library `Bio`. Why would that be and how can I resolve this?

*EDIT 1*: Same result (of course) when calling script directly.

```
michael$ bash TESTING
EEE
======================================================================
ERROR: CheckingOps__unittest (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: CheckingOps__unittest
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ImportError: No module named 'Bio'
```

Comment: I'm curious about your abuse of process substitution. The first process substitution probably works because your unit tests write to stderr and nothing to stdout. The second is trivially unnecessary, `bash TESTING` could have been used. Do you have any python-related variables set and unexported?

Comment: @muru Same result when running `bash TESTING` (see edited answer). I do not have any global variables set.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't modified `PYTHONPATH`? What if you run `python -Em unittest discover -s ./lib/ -p '*__unittest.py'`?

Comment: @muru Running `python -Em unittest discover -s ./lib/ -p '*__unittest.py'` from the commandline works, but echoing to `TESTING` first and then running `TESTING` doesn't.

Comment: What if you run `bash -c "python -m unittest discover -s ./lib/ -p '*__unittest.py'"`?

Comment: @muru Interestingly, when adding the `-c` flag, the command fails! Why could that be?

Comment: My bet's still on an unexported environment variable, though it's not one of the Python ones (or `python -E` would have failed).